# Extracting points along a line - Python

Tags: numpy, ezdxf

Along a known line, I am trying to extract a list of point at set distances from the end of the line. e.g. 30cm and 65cm from the end of the line.

I have been exploring ezdxf but haven't found a simple function to achieve this.

[Diagram: Known points in blue, required positions marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlK7V.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As stated, it's more of a maths problem than a Python problem. A hint: find a parametrization of the line as a function of distance, something like p = (p1 + k (p2 - p1)) where p1 and p2 are endpoint coordinates and k is a distance parameter. Set a suitable value for k and you have your point.